# Convert Word doc file to docx on a server without Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I would like to use c#  to convert a doc file to docx file.

Can this be done without Word on a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx). It's not free but it is good.

Answer (score 8):

http://b2xtranslator.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it is possible without Word installed.

Have a look at this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/f51bdd0c-b022-45c6-8af5-6ed79ad576fd/

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenOffice to convert. It support .doc format. About docx format I'm not sure.