# Convert .doc to .docx with c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I got a bunch (10k+) of documents, it's actually not only .doc but also .ppt and .xls files that needs to be converted to docx, pptx and xlsx. I am to upload these documents to SharePoint and have an environment with SharePoint, Visual Studio, Office 2010 Pro and so on.

Are there any best practices to perform this? 
I've been looking a bit at Aspose.Words but 2500 usd seems a bit over the top for a one time conversion.

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803576/convert-word-doc-file-to-docx-on-a-server-without-word  Look at the link provided by Tony the Lion.

Comment: Something to consider - MS Office not recomeneded in server or unattended mode. Might get away running as 'batch' on an app server but not on a web server in response to user events like uploading files. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317316

Comment: Im dont usually do this kind of imports in a webapp, ever. I have a tendency to create either console or windows apps or possibly a service application of some kind that takes a batch of documents at a time. Also, I work at a very qualified international IT consultancy agency so server power and such is pretty much unlimited, but thanks for your concern!

Comment: @Kiquenet I used the interop librarys to perform the conversion, it went quite well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Word ( and PowerPoint ) in automation from c#, [have a look here as a starting point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28office.11%29.aspx), you can loops among the old file and call the save in the new format programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use microsoft interop dll and you need to have ms office2007 or 2010. its more or less the safest way of doing. but as you are saying 10K+ docs, it will take lots of time. its a three step process.
open file. save as file and close file looped over all your files.
You can take help of the links provided in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe useful,

Convert DOC to DOCX using PowerShell

http://row5is.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/convert-doc-to-docx-using-powershell/

[Basic Powershell - batch convert Word Docx to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534292/basic-powershell-batch-convert-word-docx-to-pdf)

http://kiquenet.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/convert-doc-office-97-2003-to-docx-office-2010/

IMHO, it can be port to C# easily.