# Basic Powershell - batch convert Word Docx to PDF

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to use PowerShell to do a batch conversion of Word Docx to PDF - using a script found on this site:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/24/weekend-scripter-convert-word-documents-to-pdf-files-with-powershell.aspx

```
# Acquire a list of DOCX files in a folder
$Files=GET-CHILDITEM "C:\docx2pdf\*.DOCX"
$Word=NEW-OBJECT –COMOBJECT WORD.APPLICATION

Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    # open a Word document, filename from the directory
    $Doc=$Word.Documents.Open($File.fullname)

    # Swap out DOCX with PDF in the Filename
    $Name=($Doc.Fullname).replace("docx","pdf")

    # Save this File as a PDF in Word 2010/2013
    $Doc.saveas([ref] $Name, [ref] 17)  
    $Doc.close()
}
```

And I keep on getting this error and can't figure out why:

```
PS C:\docx2pdf> .\docx2pdf.ps1
Exception calling "SaveAs" with "16" argument(s): "Command failed"
At C:\docx2pdf\docx2pdf.ps1:13 char:13
+     $Doc.saveas <<<< ([ref] $Name, [ref] 17)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any ideas?

Also - how would I need to change it to also convert doc (not docX) files, as well as use the local files (files in same location as the script location)?

Sorry - never done PowerShell scripting...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This will work for doc as well as docx files.

```
$documents_path = 'c:\doc2pdf'

$word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

# This filter will find .doc as well as .docx documents
Get-ChildItem -Path $documents_path -Filter *.doc? | ForEach-Object {

    $document = $word_app.Documents.Open($_.FullName)

    $pdf_filename = "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.BaseName).pdf"

    $document.SaveAs([ref] $pdf_filename, [ref] 17)

    $document.Close()
}

$word_app.Quit()
```

Comment: This worked - thanks - changed $documents_path to be dynamic based on script location by using `$documents_path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`

Comment: Is oledb used in this conversion?

Comment: You should also release the COM object: `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word_app)`. Removing the entire variable is also suggested by [The Scripting Guys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx): `Remove-Variable word_app`

Comment: This results in an error: ComException on the SaveAs line.  I have not found a solution that works on windows server 2016 yet.

Comment: For anyone having problems with this version using [ref], make sure you have the latest Windows Management Framework 5.1 installed. Updating it worked for me, even when using this script on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat?view=word-pia for the enum values. for example use 7 if you want to convert to text

Comment: I changed `$documents_path = '.'` which will make it run in the current folder. Its useful to copy the script to the folder with the docs and run it there.

Answer (score 9):

The above answers all fell short for me, as I was doing a batch job converting around 70,000 word documents this way. As it turns out, doing this repeatedly eventually leads to Word crashing, presumably due to memory issues (the error was some COMException that I didn't know how to parse). So, my hack to get it to proceed was to kill and restart word every 100 docs (arbitrarily chosen number).

Additionally, when it did crash occasionally, there would be resulting malformed pdfs, each of which were generally 1-2 kb in size. So, when skipping already generated pdfs, I make sure they are at least 3kb in size. If you don't want to skip already generated PDFs, you can delete that if statement.

Excuse me if  my code doesn't look good, I don't generally use Windows and this was a one-off hack. So, here's the resulting code:

```
$Files=Get-ChildItem -path '.\path\to\docs' -recurse -include "*.doc*"

$counter = 0
$filesProcessed = 0
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $Name="$(($File.FullName).substring(0, $File.FullName.lastIndexOf("."))).pdf"
    if ((Test-Path $Name) -And (Get-Item $Name).length -gt 3kb) {
        echo "skipping $($Name), already exists"
        continue
    }

    echo "$($filesProcessed): processing $($File.FullName)"
    $Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($File.FullName)
    $Doc.SaveAs($Name, 17)
    $Doc.Close()
    if ($counter -gt 100) {
        $counter = 0
        $Word.Quit()
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word)
        $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    }
    $counter = $counter + 1
    $filesProcessed = $filesProcessed + 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (Word 2007):

```
$wdFormatPDF = 17
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.visible = $false

$folderpath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -recurse -include "*.doc" | % {
    $path =  ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
    $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
    $doc.saveas($path, $wdFormatPDF) 
    $doc.close()
}

$word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the solutions posted here worked for me on Windows 8.1 (btw. I'm using Office 365). My PowerShell somehow does not like the [ref] arguments (I don't know why, I use PowerShell very rarely).

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
$Files=Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\to\files\*.docx'

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($File.FullName)
    $Name=($Doc.FullName).replace('docx', 'pdf')
    $Doc.SaveAs($Name, 17)
    $Doc.Close()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've updated this one to work on latest office :

```
# Get invocation path
$curr_path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
# Create a PowerPoint object
$ppt_app = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
#$ppt.visible = $false
# Get all objects of type .ppt? in $curr_path and its subfolders
Get-ChildItem -Path $curr_path -Recurse -Filter *.ppt? | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing" $_.FullName "..."
    # Open it in PowerPoint
    $document = $ppt_app.Presentations.Open($_.FullName,0,0,0)
    # Create a name for the PDF document; they are stored in the invocation folder!
    # If you want them to be created locally in the folders containing the source PowerPoint file, replace $curr_path with $_.DirectoryName
    $pdf_filename = "$($curr_path)\$($_.BaseName).pdf"
    # Save as PDF -- 17 is the literal value of `wdFormatPDF`
    #$opt= [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType]::ppSaveAsPDF
    $document.SaveAs($pdf_filename,32)
    # Close PowerPoint file
    $document.Close()
}
# Exit and release the PowerPoint object
$ppt_app.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ppt_app)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since it's doing PowerPoints instead.