# Apache POI's Word to PDF - Error when converting: Bigger paragraph spacing than source

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, apache-poi, file-conversion

I am trying to converting a word document to PDF by using Apache's POI.

However, it is converting the files with bigger line heights / paragraph spacing.

Extract from Word file:

[image: Word file]

Exact same extract from Converted PDF:

[image: Converted to PDF]

As you can see, each paragraph has a much bigger spacing than originally intended, even causing it to have a page jump.

The code I am using is the following:

```
        try {
        InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File("random.docx"));
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("random.pdf"));
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

[This](https://d9db56472fd41226d193-1e5e0d4b7948acaf6080b0dce0b35ed5.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/spectools/docs/wd-spectools-word-sample-04.doc) is the input file I am using.

Dependencies include the following:

[image: Dependencies]

I need a way to eliminate this spacing, or at best reduce it as close as possible to the original way.

Your input (whatever it is) is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to use script languages (PowerShell) to do the job, or is POI a "must requirement"?

Comment: My sole requirement is to get a big list of Docs converted to PDFs. Please tell me more about this PowerShell

Comment: Here's a useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534292/basic-powershell-batch-convert-word-docx-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and found a little work-around. I created a new .docx-file and set the paragraph spacing to 0. Then I just copied my file contents into the new document and somehow it works now.