# Convert word doc to TEXT pdf powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, scripting, ms-word, automation

I have some powershell code that transforms a word document into a pdf.  It works fairly well, but there's one problem.  For whatever reason the pdf gets created as a pdf image instead of text during conversion..  I NEED text unfortunately.  There has to be some parameters that I can pass in to change this.  Has anyone out there ran into this?

Here is the code

```
$Path = "SomePath"
$OutPath = "SomePath"
$Ftype = $Path + "*.doc"
$NewSuffix = ".pdf"
##  invoke WORD application
##
$word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word_app.visible = $False
##
##   Get the files from the folder
##
$files = Get-ChildItem $Ftype
##
##   process each file - open in WORD and save as PDF in output folder
##   then delete original WORD file
##
write-host "Starting DOC Conversion"
ForEach ($file in $files) { 
    $d2 = $file.name
    $Out = $OutPath + $d2 -replace ".doc", $NewSuffix
    #$Out = $Out -replace '\s',''
    $LogLine = "Converting from " + $file.fullname + " to " + $Out
    $LogLine >>'C:\temp\WordPDF.LOG'
    write-host $LogLine
    $document = $word_app.Documents.Open($file.fullname)
    $document.SaveAs($Out, 17)
    $document.Close()
    $Dcounter = $Dcounter + 1
    $Wcounter = $Wcounter + 1
    if ($Deletefiles) {
        Remove-Item $file 
        write-host "Deleting " $file.fullname
        }
}
$word_app.Quit()
```

Comment: i think interop always write pdf like it, you cant do it.

Comment: is there an alternate way to convert a doc to pdf where it will keep the text?

Comment: the answer from [batch convert Word Docx to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534292/basic-powershell-batch-convert-word-docx-to-pdf) worked for me

Comment: search itextsharp, may be with this library

Comment: So i figured out that my word document is using a third party font and that is why it's not creating the pdf as text and rather generating an image.