# Converting Doc(x) files to PDF in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pdf, documentation

I am trying to convert Word file(s) to PDF. I have found a code that is using *ComObject Word.Application*.
However, running the command:
*$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application* returns the following error:

`New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At line:1 char:9

- $word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand`

I have MS Word installed and running fine.
I have found that my PowerShell is running 64-bit version but my Office installed as 32-bit. This may be an issue but I cannot control it as the script will be powered by 3rd party application that I have no control over and Office is installed on many computers that I really do not control also.
Can I somehow register that Class? Can I do the conversion without any 3rd party software (like Word or LibreOffice) installed? Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Need to create a PDF file

Comment: Does this answer help?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16537996/1054225

Comment: I would make sure you’re not running as admin, because if word is already open unelevated, you can’t instantiate in an elevated prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I was not running as Admin.

However, I noticed that the same script was running fine on my other computer and everything seems the same on both of them. So, I have done the "repair" of the Office installation and that has fixed the issue.