# How read ".doc" file or how to Convert it to ".docx" using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, .doc

Here are two problems that I am facing, among these two problems one should be solved, to make my project work.

So Here are those:

1. How to read ".doc" file, **without using Word automation or any paid SDK like Aspose.Words**.

   (If first one is not possible then)
2. How to convert ".doc" file to ".docx"? **without using Word automation or any paid SDK like Aspose.Words**.

Searched a lot, I found open source solution for .docx only.

**This is to be done on Server so no Word installed there.**

Comment: Reference thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803576/convert-word-doc-file-to-docx-on-a-server-without-word

Comment: Further reference thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405417/automation-how-to-automate-transforming-doc-to-docx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) - it's written in .NET and is free and open source. The [roadmap](http://npoi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NPOI%20Road%20Map&referringTitle=Documentation) intends to support creation of the new formats in future, but for now you could use it to read the old format and use other solutions to write the new one, which is an open standard (see [the MS spec here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669147.aspx)).

Comment: At this stage this library still doesn't appear to support reading .doc files for production use.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to give this pure .NET solution a shot:

> [**b2xtranslator**](http://b2xtranslator.sourceforge.net/)

It does not require you to install any Office application on the server.

Comment: Can you add a sample of use?

Comment: @zed I've [upgraded this to .NET Core](https://github.com/EvolutionJobs/b2xtranslator) and an example would be `b2xtranslator.WordprocessingMLMapping.Converter.Convert(new WordDocument(StructuredStorageReader(fileName)), WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName + "x", DocumentType.Document))`

Comment: This is a Microsoft recommanded way to interop with native Office format : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/interoperability/binary-to-open-xml-b2x-translator-interoperability-for-the-office-binary-file-formats

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same problem. If you want to convert .doc to .docx you can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library. It works for me. Here is the code.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Word._Application application = new Word.Application();
            object fileformat = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument;
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\abc");
            foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                if (file.Extension.ToLower() == ".doc")
                {
                    object filename = file.FullName;
                    object newfilename = file.FullName.ToLower().Replace(".doc", ".docx");
                    Word._Document document = application.Documents.Open(filename);

                    document.Convert();
                    document.SaveAs(newfilename, fileformat);
                    document.Close();
                    document = null;
                }
            }
            application.Quit();
            application = null;




        }
    }
}
```

It will work for you also..

Comment: Is the document.Convert() line necessary? It is giving me issues and I would think the .SaveAs() would also handle the converting into the fileformat argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OpenXML SDK` if you want open source. or else there is a option in .NET using Interop.Word API. You can open file using this api and save it as docx.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

But this needs word to be installed at the machine.

Comment: Op specified no Word install possible.

Answer (score 1):

There was a Microsoft Bulk Conversion Tool which did this. I've found a [reference here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/19/bulk-convert-doc-to-docx.aspx)

Otherwise I think you have no choice but to use Word Automation. After all, even OpenOffice has trouble opening some .doc files and converting them to .docx / OpenXML, which implies writing any sort of parsing tool yourself is going to be troublesome.

Comment: This requires **Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack** to be installed on server, so this not the right one.

Comment: Two points: 'no Word' was specified in the original post. I think MS Office Compatibility Pack can be installed independently. Secondly, the utilities in there which you might use for this, such as ' "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\wordconv.exe" -oice -nme <input file> <output file>', might work on their own, or with few dependencies. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: I agreed, but i am not sure about this because, its not my own server, I am going to take space from an hosting provider, so this may causes problem with some hosts.

Comment: Sure, I understand the issue with hosting, it's a pain. You may find that you can deploy wordconv.exe (and perhaps one or two other dependent dlls) with your website and execute it from within your code. Not sure how this would fly license-wise! :-)