# InvalidDataException by saving an OpenXml document

Tags: c#, exception, openxml, wordprocessingml

My code is intended to create a docx document, taking the parts from more documents and merge them into one.

```
private void CopyContent(WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc, WordprocessingDocument targetDoc)
{
    // copy parts from source document to new document
    foreach (var part in sourceDoc.Parts)
        targetDoc.AddPart(part.OpenXmlPart, part.RelationshipId);

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(sourceDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(targetDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
    targetDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}
```

The code is only a snipped, it works fine for `docx` created by Office 2013, but it fails if the document was a `doc` (created by an older version of office)  saved as docx by Office 2013.
It rises the following error once `targetDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save()` is executed.

```
{"The root XML element \"http://purl.oclc.org/ooxml/wordprocessingml/main:document\" in the part is incorrect. The expected root XML element is: \"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:document\"."}
```

What does it mean? How could I solve it?

Comment: Exactly which steps did you use to turn this into a docx?

Comment: From Office 2013 `Save As -> .docx`

Comment: Well, from the error message you show, the document has been saved as Word 2003 XML, not as a Word 2013 docx (Word Open XML). Possibly, the file needs to be opened again in the Word UI and the CONVERT function used, either in VBA or using File/Convert in the UI.

Comment: Wouldn't a `Word 2003 XML` have an .xml extension?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `.doc` file to `.docx` before processing it. To achieve that you can use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` library.

Some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100470/how-read-doc-file-or-how-to-convert-it-to-docx-using-asp-net)

Comment: But i'm not loading a doc file... i have a docx file which WAS a doc.