# Is that possible to convert doc file to docx programatically in C# by using openxmlsdk 2.0?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have to convert .doc file to .docx file programatically in C#(4.0) by using openxmlsdk 2.0.

could you please suggest me some of the approach for doing this by using openxmlsdk or without openxmlsdk interface?

Comment: what does the documentation say? what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert .doc document to .docx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309090/convert-doc-document-to-docx)

Comment: @Oliver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309090/convert-doc-document-to-docx is not found, 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803576/convert-word-doc-file-to-docx-on-a-server-without-word)** here they have given the solution for your question.

**[Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx)** for .NET

Aspose.Words for .NET is an advanced component and class library for .NET that enables you to perform a wide range of document processing tasks directly within your .NET applications.

Aspose.Words for .NET supports DOC, OOXML, RTF, HTML, OpenDocument, PDF, XPS, EPUB and other formats. With Aspose.Words you can view, generate, modify, convert, render and print documents without using Microsoft Word.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309090/convert-doc-document-to-docx not found

Comment: This was a duplicate question which has been closed.